# Wrong example in Package ‘xlsReadWrite’ pdf guide?

Tags: r, export-to-excel

At the following link you can find the pdf guide of the xls.ReadWrite package

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsReadWrite/xlsReadWrite.pdf

Running on R this code available at page 8 (xls.write function):

```
myval <- data.frame(
Fertility = c(80.2, 83.1, 92.5),
Agriculture = c(17, 45.1, 39.7),
Testlogical = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
Education = as.integer(c(12, 9, 5)),
Catholic = c(9.96, 84.84, 93.4),
Infant.Mortality = c(22.2, 22.2, 20.2),
Testcharacter = c("Co", "De", "Fr"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# write the data.frame...
write.xls(myval, "mytest.xls")
```

... I get the following error:

```
Error in .Call("WriteXls", x, file, colNames, sheet, from - 1, rowNames,  : 
  Incorrect number of arguments (7), expecting 6 for 'WriteXls'
```

How can I explain this strange behaviour?

Comment: I recently got the same message when using the package.  I don't usually write to Ecel but had the need.  I chalked the error up to my ignorance, wrote it out as a CSV and then converted in Excel to xlsx.  If others confirm this behavior in the package it is wise to contact the maintainer. [I was on a Windows 7 machine at the time]

Comment: alternatively could also use the xlsx-package....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run this after you install the package:

```
xls.getshlib()
```

Either one of two things will happen:

1 - it will work and the package will work or 
  2 - it will complain you're not on a 32-bit OS and not work.

If it worked, your write.xls should work fine. If not just export as a csv and save it as an excel file.

Comment: I'm working on a 32-bit OS but I get an error

> xls.getshlib()
Loading required package: tools
--- xls.getshlib running... --- 
Errore in xls.getshlib() : currently only windows (32 bit) supported